# Coverage build for applications not linking to libc

Tags: c, code-coverage

Is it possible to build an executable (on unix-like systems) that uses both --coverage and -nodefaultlibs?

I just tried and and I get a disconcertingly large number of missing symbols in libgcov.a.

Are there any alternatives to gcov for measuring coverage in a C application?